# Under what conditions is a polynomial root perturbation problem singular?

Tags: polynomials, perturbation-theory

I'm interested in what we know in general and rigorously.  I've encountered lots of rules of thumb, i.e. when you change order or have a repeated root.  But I'm interested in both what we can say definitively and as generally as possible.

Comment: Probably I'm just unaware of basic perturbation theory terminology, but what do you mean by "a polynomial root perturbation problem" and "singular" in this context?

Comment: A polynomial root is what it sounds like, a perturbation problem is one where some of the coefficients of the polynomial include a small parameter, and you'd like to use this fact to approximate the roots.  Such a problem is singular when the roots when you assume that parameter is zero are not a good approximation (in some sense that every source I can find seems to only treat vaguely) for the roots when the parameter is small but non-zero.

Comment: There are not a lot of really rigorous statements in perturbation theory at all, and I don't think it's super important. I think of regular roots as being roots where an expansion like $x=\sum_{n=0}^N\epsilon^{\delta_n}x_n$ works well for $0\leq\delta_0<\delta_1<\ldots$, and a singular root as requiring $\delta_0<0$. This is not completely true but its something.